# Gmail API message.list from trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

I am having a problem creating an google script that would run every night. The code runs fine when I run it from the script file and behaves as expected, however when performed by an installed trigger I get the following:

> TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined. (line 17, file "Main")

**EDIT:** *To be clear I know that the particular query used has to return results as running the same script from the script editor works fine*

**Code:**

```
function doGet(query) {
  var sSheet = sheetSelect(),  //calls spreadsheet selection function and assigns the spreadsheet to variable
      queriedMessages,         //object to store the queried messages list
      pageToken,               //string token value that will be pulled from the queredMessages
      auth = 'me';

  if (!query) query = 'in:all newer_than:1d -is:chats -in:trash';
  do {
    queriedMessages = Gmail.Users.Messages.list(auth, {'q':query, 'pageToken':pageToken});  //callls the Gmail API to query messages
    dataOutput(sSheet, queriedMessages.messages, queriedMessages.messages.length);          //calls function to output all data to spreadsheet from the current list
        pageToken = queriedMessages.nextPageToken;                                              //gets the next page token from the list
      }

  while (pageToken);                                                                        //the loop is executed until there are no more next page tokens left
}
```

Any ideas why it behaves so differently? I have tried providing userId for a specific e-mail. Seems like this might be some kind of authentication issue but I cannot figure out how to fix it other than forgetting about Gmail API and go a roundabout way of using Gmail App as it seems to be an issue with Gmail API method messages.list()

Thank You for any help in advance!

---

I managed to fix the issue. The problem was me wanting to leave an option to pass on a query with the function call. The problem then is that the installed trigger actually passed on a variable to the query variable and a new one is then not set.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's much simpler than that. If I list messages in the last day, I get:

**Request:**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?q=newer_than%3A1d
```

**Response:**

```
{
 "messages": [
    {
     "id": "150612f9d7f83db9",
     "threadId": "150611d4e92b7a5f"
    }, ...
  ]
}
```

If I list messages in the last second, I get:

**Request:**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?q=newer_than%3A1s
```

**Response:**

```
{
 "resultSizeEstimate": 0
}
```

In other words, `queriedMessages.messages` will be `undefined` if you get no messages with that particular query, and `queriedMessages.messages.length` will give rise to your error.

Comment: However that particular query should return messages. I attempted to run the script from the editor and then by trigger a minute later. When run by trigger it did not return anything but when run from the editor it returned 63 messages.

It seems like the trigger does not run the app as the user or does not have the authentication to see the e-mails for a user if I specify my e-mail instead of using the 'me' identifier